Do Drupal 10 Webform Handlers update CivicRM Activity data?
I have a Drupl 10 webform (6.2.2) and I'd like to set a particular CiviCRM Activity datafield on it to a value when the webform is updated.
This all appears to work, but only on the webform submission data.  If I look at the webform submission, I can see the data has been correctly changed by the handler, but when I look at the actual CiviCRM Activity data, it has not been changed at all.
It is odd, as if I manually change anything on the form, that is correctly updated on the Activity, but the data handler will still write it to the submission itself so the data is out of sync.  I have tried moving the handler above the Create some data in CiviCRM, but this has no affect. It looks like the webform data on the form is saved to civicrm and then the handler does its job.  This does not seem right?
This handler is a powerful and useful feature and I just want to know if I am using it correctly.
